# Password Encrypyed Cert on Python (based on PHP / guzzle code)

Tags: python, http, python-requests, pkcs#12

I need to access a WebPageTest API that requires an password-encrypted cert file. I am migrating this from a PHP app that uses guzzle where it currently works w/o issue.

The main issue I am having is that it seems like you can't send a password with a cert file in python (requests or urllib).

I am comfortable enough with python and its http tools. BUT I can't seem to find any documentation indicating exactly how to do this. I see the question asked in forums, but unless I am missing something it is still not resolved.

Here is my guzzle code (with obvious changes to paths etc):

```
$wpt = $guzzle->get($wpt_server . 'runtest.php', [
'query' => $query_args,
'cert' => "path/to/cert.crt",
'ssl_key' => ["path/to/key.key", "MyKeyP@ssword"]
]);
```

I don't have any python code to sare as this is more a "can it be done" question.

Comment: Requests doesn't currently support it - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification - you can use one unencrypted (where is the password stored now? plain text somewhere?) or keep a small php script around to perform this task that python can shell out to.

Comment: you could use local proxy server to see request send by PHP - with all headers, cookies and body - and then you can try to recreate request with the same headers, cookies and body using Python. You can create all elements manually and then add to request.